# Live Chat (Node.js) Custom Font Assistance Needed

Tags: html, css, fonts, web

Still relatively new to HTML/CSS and currently working on a Live Chat feature for my website utilizing Node.js and MongoDB. I've been able to get the chat to work, but have been stuck on figuring out how to customize a specific aspect of this chat. I'd like to change the font-weight of the username in the chat box (area where all messages are seen) to make the username stand out a bit more compared to the rest of the text in the box. I am confused on how to do so in CSS. I've highlighted (in yellow) the line where the 'Username' is called so I imagine this is the 'class' that I'd need to customize but it tied to the text afterwards if that makes sense...?

Thanks for your help!

[image: Wrap Text]

[Browser Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKUJV.png)

[What my code and chat currently look like (see line 59 for highlighted portion)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIhMZ.png)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chat">
            <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Chat">
            <div class="info-rect">Info</div>
            <div class="chat-messages"></div>
            <textarea placeholder="Join the conversation..."></textarea>
            <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

        <script>
            (function() {
                var getNode = function(s) {
                    return document.querySelector(s);
                },

                // Get required nodes
                status = getNode('.chat-status span'),
                messages = getNode('.chat-messages'), 
                textarea = getNode('.chat textarea'),
                chatName = getNode('.chat-name'),

                statusDefault = status.textContent,    

                setStatus = function(s){
                    status.textContent = s;

                    if(s !== statusDefault){
                        var delay = setTimeout(function(){
                            setStatus(statusDefault);
                            clearInterval(delay);
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                };

                //try connection
                try{
                   var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
                } catch(e){
                    //Set status to warn user
                }

                if(socket !== undefined){

                    //Listen for output
                    socket.on('output', function(data){
                        if(data.length){
                            //Loop through results
                            for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1){
                                var message = document.createElement('div');
                                message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
                                message.textContent = data[x].name + ': ' + data[x].message;

                                //Append
                                messages.appendChild(message);
                                messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    //Listen for a status
                    socket.on('status', function(data){
                        setStatus((typeof data === 'object') ? data.message : data);

                        if(data.clear === true){
                            textarea.value = '';
                        }
                    });

                    //Listen for keydown
                    textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
                        var self = this,
                            name = chatName.value;

                        if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false){
                            socket.emit('input', {
                                name: name,
                                message: self.value
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }

            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: better to inspect from the browser and find the css selector. The dev tools of the browser will tell you which css file and selector affects the username class and you can modify the font from there

Comment: Great idea, however it looks like both the username and text element both utilize the same class 'chat-message' so changing that would change both. I've added a screenshot of this to my original post

Comment: you can use .chat-message:first-of-type pseudo selector or :first-child

Comment: oh... i see what you mean. You will need to wrap the name text in a div and add the class and styling to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a css selector to the name:

```
 var message = document.createElement('div');
    message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
    message.textContent = ': ' + data[x].message;
 var name=document.createElement('span');
    name.setAttribute('class', 'userName');
    name.textContent = data[x].name;

    message.insertBefore(name, message.firstChild);
```

Then for css:

```
.userName{
   font-weight: 700;
}
```

Here's a fiddle for you to see the results: https://jsfiddle.net/p4yfxLd0/

Comment: We're certainly narrowing down this issue, although when I replace the line of html with the one you've written, it just states what you have typed within the quotation marks, I've added another image to the original post to show (may take 1 minute for me to get it up)

Comment: replace the var message setting with the update code. Keep the stuff after //append line. This will create a DOM element of span and insert it in the chat message div, then append the whole thing to the message body

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much, looks like I have some reading up to do about DOM. Really appreciate the help

Comment: Glad to help! please choose this as selected answer so anyone else who has a similar problem can reference.